# Show that the discontinuities of $f$ are contained in $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup\dots$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f_k \to f$ uniformly on $A \subset R^n$. Let $A_k$ be the points of discontinuity of $f_k$. Show that the discontinuities of $f$ are contained in $A_1 \cup A_2\cup\dots$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0$ be any point of discontinuity of $f$, and let $\epsilon > 0$ be small enough so that for any $\delta>0$, some $x$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|>\epsilon$. By uniform convergence of $f_k$, there exists an $N>0$ such that $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for every $k>N$ and $x \in \mathbb R$.

Thus if $k>N$ and $|f(x)-f(x_0)|>\epsilon$, then the triangle inequality implies $|f_k(x)-f_k(x_0)|>\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. This shows $f_k$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ for all $k>N$, which is actually a stronger result than the one stated in your problem.

Comment: Nice answer, Dustan.